# Preventing reverse polairty in NiMH batteries

Tags: batteries, polarity

So, I am powering The Device.  It's low power, running at <10mA.  Minimum voltage required is 3.5V, so using NiMH rechargeable batteries you need 4 in series.

My problem is that they discharge, leaving 3 at ~1.1V and the final battery at 0.02V, ish.  This is bad for the battery - but I can't see any way of preventing this.  All the reverse polarity suggestions I've seen appear to care about protecting The Device.  I want to care for my batteries!

Ideas?

Comment: the solution uses a reference voltage and series MOSFET switch, however I would recommend LiPo 3.6 instead with a single 16850 cell

Comment: Are your cells not matched?

Comment: I did something a little bit like this once in a consumer product. You may be able to use FET's, one in series with each cell.

Comment: Now that I think about it, what I was doing was a bit different. The fear was that the user would put in the battery backwards. We didn't want to use mechanical polarity protection, so I had to come up with an electrical solution. But I think what you are worried about is the case where discharge continues after cell voltage is very low or zero (thus reversing the cell with lowest capacity). I have to think about it for a bit.

Comment: ThreePhaseEel: The batteries are brand new, perfectly matched.  In theory.

MKeith: Correct, it's the over discharge bit I'm worried about.   The Device has a diode on it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea. It may not work. We really want a FET that will stay on reliably down to 0.9 or 0.8V. I am not sure if there is anything available that will do that. I suspect that this will work OK most of the time, but if you make a lot of units, or if you try to operate in cooler temperatures, it may cut off too early, effectively shortening battery life.

Note that the NMOS FET has its source connected to the battery negative terminal, and its gate connected to the positive terminal. As long as the battery voltage is high enough, the FET will be on, and current will flow through it freely. At some point as the battery discharges, the FET will turn off, and at that point, it will stop discharging.

You would still be able to charge it, as current will flow from source to drain through the FET's body diode until the cell voltage recovers enough to turn the FET on again. In theory.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN4CO1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Goalpost move - this device will run outside, in an unheated box.  Subzero temperatures aren't going to be good...

Comment: You could try it out. Are the NiMH batteries going to be OK at subzero?

Comment: They cut out for ~10 hours last night, when it got really quite cold.  Not sure if it was just under voltage, or no voltage.

Comment: Was this with the FET's in there, or just the batteries in series by themselves? I suppose you could implement something like a BMS for the cells. Power the "BMS" from the full battery pack, but monitor each cell voltage independently, and disconnect the pack when any cell gets down to 0.8 or 0.6.

Comment: That was just the batteries - and it was voltage drop due to cold.  Moved up to 6 NiMH, seeing if that helps at all... so far, so good?  But nights have been warmer.